# pdflib : Show on browser and save on server in the same time a pdf file

Tags: php, pdf, web, pdflib

Is somebody know how to **show** on browser and **save** on server in the same time a pdf file?
I use PHP and PDFLIB to generate the pdf,
and in the beginning i do :

`PDF_open_file ($p, $DocFile);`

Where $DocFile indicate the place on server where i write the pdf.
And at the end , when i finished generating the pdf, in order to save the pdf somewhere on the server ,i do :

`$b = PDF_close ($p);
 $b = PDF_delete ($p);`

I can save the file on the server but what i want to do now is to be able to save the pdf on the server and the same time display it on the browser.
How can i do that?
Im using Pdflib v7 with php v5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the solution, i put it here if somebody need:

`<?
    PDF_open_file ($p, "/tmp/test.pdf");
    $pdf = pdf_new();
    pdf_open_file($pdf, "/tmp/test.pdf");
    pdf_set_info($pdf, "Author", "Horvath Tamas");
    pdf_set_info($pdf, "Title", "Szamla");
    pdf_set_info($pdf, "Creator", "ARBOMedia.net Kft");
    pdf_set_info($pdf, "Subject", "Szamla");
    pdf_begin_page($pdf, 595, 842);
    pdf_add_outline($pdf, "Page 1");
    pdf_set_font($pdf, "Times-Roman", 30, "host");
    pdf_set_value($pdf, "textrendering", 1);
    pdf_show_xy($pdf, "Hello world", 50, 750);
    pdf_moveto($pdf, 50, 740);
    pdf_lineto($pdf, 330, 740);
    pdf_stroke($pdf);
    pdf_end_page($pdf);
    pdf_close($pdf);
    pdf_delete($pdf);
    $len = filesize("/tmp/test.pdf");
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Length: $len");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=test.pdf");
    readfile("/tmp/test.pdf");
    ?>`

Comment: PDF_open_file(), PDF_begin_page() and PDF_end_page(), PDF_add_outline() are deprecated since a long time (PDFlib 6).
Please use PDF_begin_document(), PDF_begin_page_ext(), PDF_end_page_ext() or PDF_create_bookmark() instead. 
PDF_set_font() is not a valid PDFlib function. To load and set a font, please use PDF_load_font() as well PDF_setfont() where you apply the font handle which you get from PDF_load_font().

Answer (score 1):

The solution Rina Certi offer is fine in general, (except some wrong usage of some APIs), but you can also do it the other way around:

- create the PDF in memory
- retrieve the PDF file via PDF_get_buffer() from memory, and send this to the client **and**  save this data to disc, by using the PHP fwrite() or file_put_contents().

BTW, PDF_open_file(), PDF_close() are deprecated since PDFlib 6. 
Please use PDF_begin_document() and PDF_end_document() instead. 
To load and set a font, please use